# Upload a video from a client computer directly to Youtube with the Youtube API v3?

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

On my website, I want my users to upload videos directly to the Youtube server without hosting them on my server. Is this possible?

I have been searching for solutions but the only ones I found were for the Youtube API v2 which is deprecated.

And in every tutorial that I found (not many by the way) they used a `$videopath` var that contains the path to the video but that is not what I'm looking for.

I want my users to upload directly to a Youtube account where all the videos are going to be uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently worked on this exact requirement. Try this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript. You have to enable the YouTube API for data access. Its all in the documentation if  you follow the above link

Answer (score 0):

Because of Copyright Violation and probably responsibility they first have to upload it to your server. That way, it will always be *you* who uploads to youtube.